# How do I turn off email notifications when transferring ownership?

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I am setting up an api and need to change the ownership of some files in my drive from my service account to my non-service account. How do I turn off the email notifications? I've tried via both Python [as well as via the docs (at the bottom of the page)](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert). The emails are getting really annoying.

```
new_permission = {'value': 'me@example.com', 'type': 'user', 'role': 'owner', 'sendNotificationEmails':'false'}
self.service.permissions().insert(fileId=self.doc['copied']['id'], body=new_permission, sendNotificationEmails='false').execute()
```

Comment: Just double checking... but at least with the JS API sendNotificationEmails is set with a boolean rather than a string. Have you tried using sendNotificationEmails=False ?

        gapi.client.drive.permissions.insert({
            'fileId': docID,
            'sendNotificationEmails': false,
            'resource': body
        }).execute(function (response)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Grant mentions in the comment, use the boolean `false` rather than the string `'false'`.

Since you are changing the owner of a documentation, sendNotificationEmails is ignored, as [per the documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert):

> Whether to send notification emails when sharing to users or groups.
>   This parameter is ignored and an email is sent if the `role` is `owner`.
>   (Default: `true`)

Comment: this doesn't work for me anymore, cant find the problem though

    batch.add(service.permissions().create(
        fileId=file_id,
        body=user_permission,
        sendNotificationEmails = False,
        fields='id',
        ))

Comment: for v3, it is `sendNotificationEmail`, singular. Check [here](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/python/latest/drive_v3.permissions.html#create)